# SOQL - Get results in same order as in query

Tags: soql, query

How can I get results for query on same order as listed on query itself.

**Example:**

(Let's suppose all records with that BackendId__c exist)

```
SELECT BackendId__c, Name, id FROM Account WHERE BackendId__c IN ('6','2','3','4')
ORDER BY ... ?
```

Result should be:

```
BackendId__c Name id
6 John a092p000
2 Mary a092p012
3 Mike a092p031
4 Adam a092p031
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The order of query results is [undefined](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm#!) if you don't use an explicit `ORDER BY` clause:

> You can use ORDER BY in a SELECT statement to control the order of the query results. There is no guarantee of the order of results unless you use an ORDER BY clause in a query.

`ORDER BY` sorts by the value of the field, not by the order of specified parameters in the query.

If you need your results ordered in a specific way that does not correspond to sorting by any field in a normal lexicographic/numeric/datewise sort, consider implementing a wrapper class in Apex that implements the [`Comparable`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm#!) interface to encapsulate your custom logic. You can then call `sort()` on a list of wrapper objects.

This approach is demonstrated in the [documentation, here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_list_sorting_sobject.htm), with Opportunities, but structurally your solution would be the same.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Could you please demonstrate how to use ORDER BY clause, for listed example ?

Comment: @ferret96 `ORDER BY` does not apply to your situation, because you do not want the records sorted by the value of a field. If you did `ORDER BY BackendId__c`, you would get back 2, 3, 4, and 6, in that order.

Comment: What about using CASE ? I found this, but I'm not sure how to implement it on my example: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53628/order-field-by-list-in-soql-select

Comment: That's a formula field, not a SOQL clause.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.